# Pass multiple parameters in view when using a string to call a JS function in MVC3

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, parameter-passing

I am calling a function with one parameter "modalXPTO.HtmlFieldPrefix" sucessfuly like this:

```
modalXPTO.AdditionalJavaScriptCallback = "myFunction('" + modalXPTO.HtmlFieldPrefix + "')";
```

However, I would like to send more than one parameter, and I would expect this should work:

```
modalXPTO.AdditionalJavaScriptCallback = "myFunction('" + "{parentContainer:" + modalXPTO.ModalDivId + ", htmlFieldPrefix:" + modalXPTO.HtmlFieldPrefix + "}" + "')";
```

But it doesn't. Can anyone tell me what I am missing?

Here is the myFuntion declaration:

```
function myFunction(arg){

alert(arg.htmlFieldPrefix);
alert(arg.parentContainer);
}
```

Comment: How does `myFunction` declaration looks like? If it actually expects two parameters, than it should be `"myFunction('" + modalXPTO.ModalDivId + "', '" + modalXPTO.HtmlFieldPrefix + "')"`.

Comment: It expects one parameter that is an object with these two values, see my edit, @Andrei.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed it.

```
modalXPTO.AdditionalJavaScriptCallback = "myFunction(" + "{parentContainer:'" + modalXPTO.ModalDivId + "', htmlFieldPrefix:'" + modalXPTO.HtmlFieldPrefix + "'}" + ")";
```

It is because of the misplaced "'". I wanted to pass an object with two parameters, but because of these characters I was passing a string instead.